# Need help making a Morse Code to Text Translator | Python

Tags: python, morse-code

so I'm having some trouble making a morse code to text translator. I made the text to morse however, When I tried making morse to text, It didnt work out. I looked up online and since I'm new to python I couldnt really understand most of it so I decided to make one on my own. It works as long as there are no spaces, but when there are spaces, I get this error.

```
Text to Morse or Morse to Text
Please type ttm for text to morse or type mtt for morse to text.
mtt
What would you like to have be translated to English?
.... ..  . ...- . .-. -.-- --- -. .
hiTraceback (most recent call last):
 File "main.py", line 61, in <module>
   print(mtt_dict[words], end="")
KeyError: ''
```

I translated "hi everyone" and it didnt really work

Here's the code:

```
ttm_dict = { 'a':'.-', 'b':'-...', 
                    'c':'-.-.', 'd':'-..', 'e':'.', 
                    'f':'..-.', 'g':'--.', 'h':'....', 
                    'i':'..', 'j':'.---', 'k':'-.-', 
                    'l':'.-..', 'm':'--', 'n':'-.', 
                    'o':'---', 'p':'.--.', 'q':'--.-', 
                    'r':'.-.', 's':'...', 't':'-', 
                    'u':'..-', 'v':'...-', 'w':'.--', 
                    'x':'-..-', 'y':'-.--', 'z':'--..', 
                    '1':'.----', '2':'..---', '3':'...--', 
                    '4':'....-', '5':'.....', '6':'-....', 
                    '7':'--...', '8':'---..', '9':'----.', 
                    '0':'-----', ', ':'--..--', '.':'.-.-.-', 
                    '?':'..--..', '/':'-..-.', '-':'-....-', 
                    '(':'-.--.', ')':'-.--.-'}

mtt_dict = {'-.--.-':')' ,'.--.-':'('                    
 ,'-....-':'-' ,'.-..-':'/' ,'..--..':'?'                    
 ,'-.-.-.':'.' ,'--..--':' ,' ,'-----':'0'                    
 ,'.----':'9' ,'..---':'8' ,'...--':'7'                    
 ,'....-':'6' ,'.....':'5' ,'-....':'4'                    
 ,'--...':'3' ,'---..':'2' ,'----.':'1'                    
 ,'..--':'z' ,'--.-':'y' ,'-..-':'x'                    
 ,'--.':'w' ,'-...':'v' ,'-..':'u'                    
 ,'-':'t' ,'...':'s' ,'.-.':'r'                    
 ,'-.--':'q' ,'.--.':'p' ,'---':'o'                    
 ,'.-':'n' ,'--':'m' ,'..-.':'l'                    
 ,'-.-':'k' ,'---.':'j' ,'..':'i'                    
 ,'....':'h' ,'.--':'g' ,'.-..':'f'                    
 ,'.':'e' ,'..-':'d' ,'.-.-':'c'                    
 ,'...-':'b' ,'-.':'a'
}
question = input("Text to Morse or Morse to Text\nPlease type ttm for text to morse or type mtt for morse to text.\n")

#Text to Morse
if question == "ttm":
  encrypt_q = input("What would you like have be translated to Morse Code\n")
  encrypt = encrypt_q.lower()
  morse = "" 
  for letter in encrypt: 
    encrypt.lower()
    if letter != ' ': 

            morse += ttm_dict[letter] + ' '
    else: 

            morse += ' '
  print(morse) 
  #Morse to Text
elif question == "mtt":
  decrypt = input("What would you like to have be translated to English?\n")
  lenword = len(decrypt)
  words = ''
  for i in decrypt:
    if i != ' ':
        words=words+i
        if i not in mtt_dict:
            print('Data not formatted properly')
            break
    else:
        print(mtt_dict[words], end="")
        words = ''

    #If they are cannot read
else:
  print("Invalid option")
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must buil an encoder/decoder, al told by @Jolbas, your problem is to separate *unequivocally* words by characters .

If the contract is single and double respectively for characters and words
you can use split in this manner:

```
<phrase>.split('  ') for word # 2 spaces
<word>.split(' ') for characters # 1 space
```

#### HIT:

So all can be done using nested list comprehension

```
[ [c for c in word] for word in phrase]
```

Using this trick the big part is solved.

This is a concise version (not all loves nested comprehension... anyway it's not too bad)

#### The code

```
ttm_dict = { 'a':'.-', 'b':'-...', 'c':'-.-.', 'd':'-..', 'e':'.',
            'f':'..-.', 'g':'--.', 'h':'....', 'i':'..', 'j':'.---', 'k':'-.-',
            'l':'.-..', 'm':'--', 'n':'-.', 'o':'---', 'p':'.--.', 'q':'--.-',
            'r':'.-.', 's':'...', 't':'-', 'u':'..-', 'v':'...-', 'w':'.--',
            'x':'-..-', 'y':'-.--', 'z':'--..', '1':'.----', '2':'..---', '3':'...--',
            '4':'....-', '5':'.....', '6':'-....', '7':'--...', '8':'---..', '9':'----.',
            '0':'-----', ', ':'--..--', '.':'.-.-.-', '?':'..--..', '/':'-..-.', '-':'-....-',
            '(':'-.--.', ')':'-.--.-'}

mtt_dict = {v:k for k,v in ttm_dict.items()}
question = input("Text to Morse or Morse to Text\nPlease type ttm for text to morse or type mtt for morse to text.\n")
if question == "ttm":
  encrypt_q = input("What would you like have be translated to Morse Code\n")
  # ' ' (single space, char separator
  # '  ' (double space) word separator
  morse = '  '.join([ ' '.join([ttm_dict[c] for c in word]) for word in encrypt_q.lower().split(' ')])
  print(morse)

elif question == "mtt":
  decrypt = input("What would you like to have be translated to English?\n")
  print(' '.join([''.join([mtt_dict[c] for c in word.split(' ')]) for word in decrypt.split('  ')]))

else:
  print("Invalid option")
```

**Here the result**:

```
Please type ttm for text to morse or type mtt for morse to text.
ttm
What would you like have be translated to Morse Code
ciao da glauco
-.-. .. .- ---  -.. .-  --. .-.. .- ..- -.-. ---

Please type ttm for text to morse or type mtt for morse to text.
mtt
What would you like to have be translated to English?
-.-. .. .- ---  -.. .-  --. .-.. .- ..- -.-. ---
ciao da glauco
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is not need of 2 saperate dict. you can achieve the conversion with one single dict. PFB code:

```
MORSE_CODE_DICT = { 'A':'.-', 'B':'-...',
                    'C':'-.-.', 'D':'-..', 'E':'.',
                    'F':'..-.', 'G':'--.', 'H':'....',
                    'I':'..', 'J':'.---', 'K':'-.-',
                    'L':'.-..', 'M':'--', 'N':'-.',
                    'O':'---', 'P':'.--.', 'Q':'--.-',
                    'R':'.-.', 'S':'...', 'T':'-',
                    'U':'..-', 'V':'...-', 'W':'.--',
                    'X':'-..-', 'Y':'-.--', 'Z':'--..',
                    '1':'.----', '2':'..---', '3':'...--',
                    '4':'....-', '5':'.....', '6':'-....',
                    '7':'--...', '8':'---..', '9':'----.',
                    '0':'-----', ', ':'--..--', '.':'.-.-.-',
                    '?':'..--..', '/':'-..-.', '-':'-....-',
                    '(':'-.--.', ')':'-.--.-'
}
question = input("Text to Morse or Morse to Text\nPlease type 'ttm' for text to morse or type 'mtt' for morse to text.\n")

#Text to Morse
if question == "ttm":
    encrypt_q = input("What would you like have be translated to Morse Code\n")
    message = encrypt_q.upper()
    cipher = ''
    for letter in message:
        if letter != ' ':
            # Looks up the dictionary and adds the correspponding morse code along with a space to separate morse codes for different characters
            cipher += MORSE_CODE_DICT[letter] + ' '
        else:
            # 1 space indicates different characters and 2 indicates different words
            cipher += ' '
    print(cipher)
#Morse to Text
elif question == "mtt":
    message = input("What would you like to have be translated to English?\n")
    # extra space added at the end to access the last morse code
    message += ' '
    decipher = ''
    citext = ''
    for letter in message:
        # checks for space
        if (letter != ' '):
            # counter to keep track of space
            i = 0
            # storing morse code of a single character
            citext += letter
            # in case of space
        else:
            # if i = 1 that indicates a new character
            i += 1
            # if i = 2 that indicates a new word
            if i == 2:
                # adding space to separate words
                decipher += ' '
            else:
                # accessing the keys using their values (reverse of encryption)
                decipher += list(MORSE_CODE_DICT.keys())[list(MORSE_CODE_DICT.values()).index(citext)]
                citext = ''
    print(decipher)
else:
    print("Invalid option")
```

Output:

Morse to text:

```
Text to Morse or Morse to Text
Please type 'ttm' for text to morse or type 'mtt' for morse to text.
mtt
What would you like to have be translated to English?
.... ..  . ...- . .-. -.-- --- -. .
HI EVERYONE
```

text to Morse:

```
Text to Morse or Morse to Text
Please type 'ttm' for text to morse or type 'mtt' for morse to text.
ttm
What would you like have be translated to Morse Code
HI EVERYONE
.... ..  . ...- . .-. -.-- --- -. .
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's when you have two spaces directly after each other. If that is supposed to mean a space between words then just add an empty string key containing a space character value in `mtt_dict` and it should work.

Then I think you should move the code that checks if key is in `mtt_dict` should be moved to the `else` part just before printing the character

```py
  for i in decrypt:
    if i != ' ':
        words += i
    else:
        if words not in mtt_dict:
            print('Data not formatted properly')
            break
        print(mtt_dict[words], end="")
        words = ''
```